# Sub-Select In hibernate criteria

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a sql table A with column names

```
name, id1, id2, val1
```

and a table B with column names

```
id1, id2, key1, key2
```

and this is my sql query

```sql
SELECT
  v1.id1,
  v1.id2
FROM (
       SELECT
         A.id1,
         A.id2,
         min(val1) AS x
       FROM A
         JOIN B ON A.id1 = B.id1 AND A.id2 = B.id2
       GROUP BY A.id1, A.id2
     ) AS v1
WHERE v1.x > 10
```

using the DetachedCriteria i was able to form the sub-query

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A_model.class);
subCriteria.createAlias("b", "b_model");
subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.groupProperty("id1"))
.add(Projections.groupProperty("id2"))
.add(Projections.min("val1"),"x");
```

but i am facing a hard time in creating the outer query.

any suggestion how can i create the criteria for the above SQL?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Criteria queries work on entities, not tables. We have no idea about what the entities look like.

Comment: @JBNizet I have provided the columns for both the tables and sql which i want. do you need any more information apart from that.
can you suggest a generic solution for sub-select through criteria?(feel free to assume any corresponding entity structure )

Answer (score 3):

Sub-selects in the `from` clause are not supported by Hibernate for the time being. However, your query can be rewritten in a simpler and more efficient form by utilizing the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT A.id1, A.id2,
FROM A JOIN B ON A.id1 = B.id1 AND A.id2 = B.id2
GROUP BY A.id1, A.id2
HAVING min(val1) > 10
```

The above query can be easily ported to HQL or Criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a view for the data you need:

```
create view A_B_BY_ID1_AND_ID2 as
select A.id1,
       A.id2,
       min( val1 ) as x
from A
join B on A.id1 = B.id1 and A.id2 = B.id2
group by A.id1,
         A.id2
```

Then create a DTO to represent this data:

```
@Entity(table="A_B_BY_ID1_AND_ID2")
@Data //are you on board with lombok?
public class ABById1AndId2 {
    @Column
    private int x;
    @Column
    private int id1;
    @Column
    private int id2;
}
```

then access it like anything else:

```
session.createCriteria(ABById1AndId2.class).add(Restrictions.gt("x", 10)).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Select from Select is neither supported by HQL nor by Criteria object. The solution here would be Named Query.

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "findV1",
    query = "SELECT
              v1.id1,
              v1.id2
            FROM (
                   SELECT
                     A.id1,
                     A.id2,
                     min(val1) AS x
                   FROM A
                     JOIN B ON A.id1 = B.id1 AND A.id2 = B.id2
                   GROUP BY A.id1, A.id2
                 ) AS v1
            WHERE v1.x > 10"
    )
})
```